# How to install memcached on openshift

Tags: django, memcached, openshift

I have a python3.3 app on openshift running django. How can I install a memcached server? I already tried

```
yum install memcached
```

but it fails (probably because I don't have privileges to do that).

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting this into a standalone cartridge for OpenShift Online and install it: https://github.com/brianredbeard/openshift-cartridges/tree/master/openshift-origin-cartridge-memcached

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this old forum post](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/memcached) can help you.

Tell here if you make it work and how, I'm testing a memcached gear for Django.

Comment: I have given up for now and I'm using [redis](https://redislabs.com/), maybe I'll be back on it in the future.